# why do some columns slow down the query

Tags: sql, database-performance, query-performance

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to optimize a query which is somehting like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 ta.id, 
              ta.name, 
              ta.amt, 
              tb.id, 
              tb.name, 
              tc.name, 
              tc.id, 
              tc.descr 
FROM   a ta 
       INNER JOIN b tb 
               ON ta.id = tb.id 
       INNER JOIN c tc 
               ON tb.id = tc.id 
ORDER  BY ta.mytime DESC
```

The query takes around 5 - 6 secs to run. There are indexes for all the columns used in joins. The tables have 500k records.

My question is: When I remove the columns tc.name, tc.id and tc.descr from the select, the query returns the results in less than a second. Why?

Comment: Because you're removing an entire table from the `JOIN`. You should start with the largest table then `JOIN` to smaller tables.

Comment: Is `c` getting written to often?

Comment: If you're using SQL Management Studio you can run the optimizer to see an execution plan. This may provide some insight as to what exactly the problem is: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to tune the query by adding additional index to the table. SQL server did not show/imply a missing index but I figured it out by creating a new non-clustered index on a field that is present in a select.

Thanks to you all for coming forward for help.

@Wade the link is really helpful in understanding the SQL optimizer the

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the execution plans to really know the difference.

As far as I know, SQL Server does *not* optimize away joins.  After all, even without columns in the select list, the joins can still be used for filtering and multiplying the number of rows.

However, one step might be skipped.  With the variables in the `select`, the engine needs to both go to the index *and* fetch the page with the data.  Without the variables, the engine does not need to do the fetch.  This may subtly tip the balance of the optimizer from one type of join to another.

A second possibility simply involves timing.  If you ran the query once, then page caches might be filled on the machine.  The second time you run it, the query goes much faster simply because the data is in memory.  Don't ever run timings unless you either (1) clear the cache between each call or (2) be sure that the cache is filled equivalently.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have clustered indexes? If not, you should create clustered indexes and run your query integer and mostly on primary key columns.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131(v=sql.80).aspx for clustered index.